# How do I make my query mysql 5.7 compliant without changing my.ini file

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1055

I have just upgraded to mysql 5.7.14 and it has caused a problem with one of my queries, and I get the error.

> #1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'salesinvoice.InvoiceDate'
>   which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;
>   this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Now the solution apparently was to edit the my.ini file and add this line

```
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Now this works, and now my query runs fine, but I would rather make my query mysql 5.7 compliant rather than having to add lines to my ini file, which might or might not work on our server. I have no access to the ini file on the server, but I have in my local server running wampserver 3.06.

Here is my query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`InvoiceDate`,'%Y-%m') as InvoiceDate,
       ROUND((SUM(`Unit_Cost`*`Quantity`)*`ExchangeRate`)+`VATValue`,2) as amount 
FROM `salesinvoice`
LEFT JOIN `salesinvoice_products`
  on `salesinvoice`.`SalesInvoice_id`=`salesinvoice_products`.`SalesInvoice_id`
WHERE `InvoiceDate` < Now()
  and `InvoiceDate` > DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL- 6 MONTH) 
GROUP BY Month(`InvoiceDate`)
```

How do I change my query to be mysql 5.7 compliant, and what does the error message really mean?

Comment: I only want it grouped by month as I am getting the monthly figures from the last six months

Comment: To get rid of the error you can `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(InvoiceDate,'%Y-%m'), ExchangeRate, VATValue`. If you think this is wrong, then your original query is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) Documentation

> **MySQL 5.7.5** and up implements detection of functional dependence. If
>   the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default),
>   MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, `HAVING` condition, or
>   `ORDER BY` list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in
>   the `GROUP BY` clause nor are functionally dependent on them. (**Before
>   5.7.5, MySQL** does not detect functional dependency and `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is not enabled by default.

To tell MySQL to accept the query, you can use the `ANY_VALUE()` function on the field which produced the error.

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(DATE_FORMAT(`InvoiceDate`,'%Y-%m')) as `formatedInvoiceDate`,
       ROUND((SUM(`Unit_Cost`*`Quantity`)*`ExchangeRate`)+`VATValue`,2) as `amount` 
FROM `salesinvoice`
LEFT JOIN `salesinvoice_products`
  on `salesinvoice`.`SalesInvoice_id`=`salesinvoice_products`.`SalesInvoice_id`
WHERE `InvoiceDate` < Now()
  and `InvoiceDate` > DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL- 6 MONTH) 
GROUP BY Month(`InvoiceDate`).
```

Alternatively, disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

A little more about `ANY_VALUE()` function can be found in MySQL Documentation on [Miscellaneous Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) (make sure to read the example).

> Synoptically, `ANY_VALUE()` function is useful for `GROUP BY` queries when the
>   `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode is enabled, for cases when MySQL rejects a
>   query that you know is valid for reasons that MySQL cannot determine.
>   The function return value and type are the same as the return value
>   and type of its argument, but the function result is not checked for
>   the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode.

Comment: Hey this worked. Can you explain a little more what this ANY_VALUE does?

Comment: @ThomasWilliams You can check [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) but it roughly does what the name suggests: tell MySQL that when it needs to choose among several values and there aren't deterministic rules to do it it's okay to choose any one them.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams my advise is check the example in ANY_VALUE it is great in order to understand this situation you are in. Very nice question.

Answer (score 1):

Your ActInvoiceDate is ambygous..

You can't use alias  in where  and you should change the name for alias 
(and you should use the same column in group by )

Your query worked fine before because previous version don't check if there are columns in select not corresponding in group by clause .. and  for 
this columns use the firts value dound when needed

so you have ExchangeRate, VATValue column not in group by   for this you could use a (fake) aggregagation function (in this case i use min) because probably these columns have constant value

```
SELECT 
      DATE_FORMAT(`InvoiceDate`,'%Y-%m') as ActInvoiceDate
      ,ROUND((SUM(`Unit_Cost`*`Quantity`)*min(`ExchangeRate`)+min(`VATValue`),2) as amount 
      FROM `salesinvoice`
LEFT JOIN `salesinvoice_products` on `salesinvoice`.`SalesInvoice_id`=`salesinvoice_products`.`SalesInvoice_id`
WHERE `InvoiceDate` < Now() and `InvoiceDate` > DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL- 6 MONTH) 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`InvoiceDate`,'%Y-%m')
```

or

```
  SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(`InvoiceDate`,'%Y-%m') as ActInvoiceDate
        ,ROUND((SUM(`Unit_Cost`*`Quantity`)*min(`ExchangeRate`))+min(`VATValue`),2) as amount 
        FROM `salesinvoice`
  LEFT JOIN `salesinvoice_products` on `salesinvoice`.`SalesInvoice_id`=`salesinvoice_products`.`SalesInvoice_id`
  WHERE `InvoiceDate` < Now() and `InvoiceDate` > DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL- 6 MONTH) 
  GROUP BY ActInvoiceDate
```

Comment: My query worked fine before the upgrade to mysql 5.7, and now it doesn't. However I tried both your queries and I still get the error #1055 - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'salesinvoice.ExchangeRate' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Your first code runs with an error on line 4 for some reason. Your second bit of code works, but is giving me slightly different values than my original query. It could be that my original query was wrong, but I need a little time to check this out, and I will get back to you

Comment: @ThomasWilliams   . ok ... remember that your versions  in  not aggregated  columns should contain not predictable values ... let me know ..

Comment: Thanks for your help, but Peter Darmis's solution did the job exactly without changing much code. However I have taken into account your suggestion about not grouping using an alias

Answer (score 0):

From [FAQ: Server SQL Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-sql-modes.html#faq-mysql-sql-mode-dependency):

> - Is the mode dependent on the database or connection?
> - A mode is not linked to a particular database. Modes can be set locally to the session (connection), or globally for the server. you
>     can change these settings using [SET [GLOBAL|SESSION]
>     sql_mode='modes'](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html).

In many platforms it's possible to run default queries on connection.

Said that, default mode got stricter and no longer allows incomplete GROUP BY clauses because it's normally a sign that the query is wrong and results are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this statement to set sql_mode

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";
```

Comment: I know I can. I already said that worked, but I have no access to ini file on server, so I want to make my code mysql 5.7 compliant rather than trying to change the server ini file

Comment: you dont need to put in INI file just use this query before fire the query like SET GLOBAL sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"; SELECT ......

Comment: You still need special privileges to set system wide values through a query (privileges a typical app should not have). Plus you're fiddling with the entire server for no good reason.